# Log Properties for Harmonic Numbers

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

It is a basic result that
$$
\log n \sim H_n \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}.
$$
We also have
$$
\log(mn) = \log m + \log n.
$$
Based on this, it seems like we should be able to prove something along the lines of: for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that when $n,m > N$
$$
\mid H_{mn} - (H_{m} + H_n) \mid < \epsilon.
$$
Is something like this true? If so, how does one go about proving it?

## Edit

Using the estimate
$$
H_n = \log n + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
We find
\begin{align}
H_{mn} - (H_m + H_n) &= \left( \log (mn) + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{mn}\right) \right) - \left(\log m + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{m}\right) + \log n + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)
\\&= -\gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{m}\right) + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}
Or, less formally, for large $m$ and large $n$
$$
H_{mn} \approx H_m + H_n - \gamma
$$
Interestingly, this gives us yet another way to calculate $\gamma$.

Comment: Taking into account Claude Leibovici's comment, you could modify your statement to $\mid H_{mn} - (H_{m} + H_n)-\gamma \mid < \epsilon$ .

Comment: True. I'll make  an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you missed an important term in the asymptotics of $H_n$

$$H_n=\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which would make
$$H_{mn}-H_m-H_n\sim-\gamma -\frac{1}{2 m}-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{2 mn}+\cdots$$

Comment: I was thinking that the euler-mascheroni constant would cancel out somehow, but I can see from your answer that it doesn't. I was foolishly attempting a direct proof, but the asymptotic equation you posted makes the result clear. Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins. Alas, $\gamma$ is still here ! You are very welcome ! Cheers :-)